# How to implement Best Fit Layout like google meet with grid using tailwind

Tags: angular, grid, tailwind-css

I want to build a video conference screen layout using Tailwindcss, I want it to fit items automatically in cols and rows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I style like this:

```
<div class="grid grid-flow-col gap-4">
    <video-app class="video" *ngFor="let video of studentsVideo" [video]="video" ></video-app>
</div>
```

it only expands columns and does not create new rows. how can I style this layout?

**Update:**

We know that we have users to join the conference. we have the length of users and we can dynamically set grid-cols-{n} and grid-rows-{n} but how we can calculate it to detect the best-fit numbers for rows and cols?

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can define variable with `grid-cols-{}` and `grid-rows-{}`, check official to use [Grid Flow](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-auto-flow#class-reference)

so try this,

```
<div class="grid grid-flow-col grid-cols-4 grid-rows-4 gap-4 bg-gray-200">
...
    <video-app class="video bg-red-300 text-center" *ngFor="let video of studentsVideo" [video]="video" >5</video-app>
    <video-app class="video bg-red-300 text-center" *ngFor="let video of studentsVideo" [video]="video" >6</video-app>
...
</div>
```

##### check [tailwind.playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/tLfubNR7u4)

#### Answer to additional question:

If you can with `javascript` then you will be able to adjust it easily :)

The Math.sqrt() function returns the square root of a number, that is

> 1 => 1

> 2 => 2

> 4 => 2*2

> 9 => 3*3

> ...

```
  const totalMembers = 4;
  const shape = round(Math.sqrt(totalMembers));
  const result = `grid-cols-${shape} grid-rows-${shape}`;
  const VideoComponent = () => <video-app class="video" *ngFor="let video of studentsVideo" [video]="video" >6</video-app>;

    return (
    <div class={`grid grid-flow-col ${result} gap-4 bg-gray-200 min-w-full`}>
        {
          let i =0;
          while (i < totalMembers) {
           return <VideoComponent />
          }
        }
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: So how do we can detect the best fit numbers for grild-cols-{} and grid-rows-{} if we have N users?

Comment: check modified one.

Comment: Just to improve your answer the calculation formula must be Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(totalMembers))

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Angular I answer in Angular too.
You can easily do this by using `[ngClass]`:

```
<div class="grid grid-flow-col"
[ngClass]="{
'grid-cols-1': currentUsers.length === 1,
'grid-cols-2': currentUsers.length > 1 && currentUsers.length <= 4,
'grid-cols-3': currentUsers.length > 4 && currentUsers.length <= 9,
'grid-cols-4': currentUsers.length > 9
}"
...
</div>
```

by using this code on your grid element you can vary the columns of the grid based on user count.

Feel free to play around with it in the **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/grids-for-adnan?file=src/app/app.component.html)** I made.

Comment: Good Idea! Look at my answer as well :D It's combinations of solutions

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @JsWizard and @Al00X,

I mixed your solutions together:

**Component.ts**

```
calculateGridLayout() {
        this.gridLayoutColsCount = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(this.studentsVideo.length));
    }
```

**Component.html**

```
<div
    [ngClass]="[
        'grid',
        'grid-cols-' + gridLayoutColsCount,
        'grid-rows-' + gridLayoutColsCount,
        'gap-4'
    ]"
>
    <video
        *ngFor="let video of studentsVideo"
        [video]="video"
    ></video>
</div>
```

Comment: Just need to whitelist grid-cols-1 to grid-cols-10 and grid-rows-1 to grid-rows-10 to make sure they are excluded from purging.

Comment: You don't really need to set the row template, `grid-flow-col` will do its job automatically.

Comment: Yes you are right.  Having just `grid-flow-col` will add extra item to the next row